# How to create a nice and smooth quality App icon?

Tags: icons

Im trying to make some custom icons in photoshop with 512x512 size, but everytime i try it in my device (galaxy tab 3) the icons looks a little pixelated. i don't understand why. I saved it with PNG-24 from photoshop and everytime looks like this.[image]

Comment: did you try to see the same icon in other screens to see if the problem is the icon or your Galaxy tab 3?

Comment: No im not able to try it in different device. but how every other icons looks perfect?

Comment: You are working in Photoshop, if you generate the PNG and open with any other graphic application (Paint in Windows or Preview in OSX), the image have the same pixelated border?  Did you try to decrease/increase the resolution to 256x256 or 1024x1024?  Maybe the galaxy tab is resizing your icon and that is generating the problem.

Comment: No when i display it on my computer everything is smooth. I try it with 1024 and looks worse. :/ I want the icon to be ready for google play. They accept 256x256 icons?

Comment: No clue, I'm just thinking what can be causing the problem.  If you see the icon smooth in your computer, maybe the problem is the resizing.  I'm just guessing.